# `LinAlgError: SVD did not converge` when attempting to rescale a 4D array using `skimage.transform.rescale`

Tags: python, image, numpy, scikit-image, rescale

I want to rescale a 4D array of MNIST data by a factor of 0.5. I get an error using `skimage.transform.rescale`:

```
LinAlgError: SVD did not converge
```

I have a feeling it might be related to image dimensions but the documentation doesn't mention image dimensions.

```
from skimage import transform
...
...
data = load_mnist() #Contains mnist data in format (50000, 1, 28, 28)
data_rescaled = transform.rescale(data, 0.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#rescale):

> **`skimage.transform.rescale(image, scale, order=1, mode='constant', cval=0, clip=True, preserve_range=False)`[[source]](http://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/transform/_warps.py#L124)**
>
> Scale image by a certain factor.
>
> Performs interpolation to upscale or down-scale images. For down-sampling N-dimensional images with integer factors by applying the arithmetic sum or mean, see `skimage.measure.local_sum` and `skimage.transform.downscale_local_mean`, respectively.
>   ...
>
> **scale : {float, tuple of floats}**
>
> Scale factors. Separate scale factors can be defined as `(row_scale, col_scale)`.

My interpretation is that `skimage.measure.rescale` only supports 2D images. A quick attempt at passing separate scaling factors for each dimension seems to confirm this:

```
In [1]: data = np.random.randn(500, 1, 28, 28)

In [2]: rescaled = transform.rescale(data, (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-638fc58c2154> in <module>()
----> 1 rescaled = transform.rescale(data, (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))

/home/alistair/.venvs/rfmap/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/transform/_warps.pyc in rescale(image, scale, order, mode, cval, clip, preserve_range)
    164 
    165     try:
--> 166         row_scale, col_scale = scale
    167     except TypeError:
    168         row_scale = col_scale = scale

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

As the documentation says, you could use `skimage.transform.local_sum` or `skimage.downscale_local_mean` instead, provided that you only need to downsample by an integer factor (in your case, 2).

Another alternative that supports using interpolation for non-integer zoom factors is [`scipy.ndimage.zoom`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom.html):

```
In [3]: from scipy import ndimage

In [4]: rescaled = ndimage.zoom(data, 0.5)

In [5]: rescaled.shape
Out[5]: (250, 1, 14, 14)
```